# Scala isAssignable From with Scala and Java primitives

Tags: scala

I have a map extension method

```
def getAs[T : Manifest](key: String): Option[T] =
  m.get(key) collect { 
    case v if manifest[T].erasure.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass) => v.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

which gets the key value and casts it to the desired type if it is assignable.
Now if the store item is say a java.lang.Boolean, and the type parameter is for scala.Boolean, then this doesn't work.  I imagine this is the same for Int, Long, etc.

Is there any obvious way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force solution

```
  def getAs[T : Manifest](key:String):Option[T] = m.get(key) collect {
    case v if manifest[T].erasure.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass)    => v.asInstanceOf[T]
    case i:java.lang.Integer if manifest[T] == manifest[Int]      => i.asInstanceOf[T]
    case l:java.lang.Long if manifest[T] == manifest[Long]        => l.asInstanceOf[T]
    case f:java.lang.Float if manifest[T] == manifest[Float]      => f.asInstanceOf[T]
    case d:java.lang.Double if manifest[T] == manifest[Double]    => d.asInstanceOf[T]
    case b:java.lang.Boolean if manifest[T] == manifest[Boolean]  => b.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```